# SkipLast of an IEnumerable<T> - Linq Extension

Tags: c#, comparative-review, linq, iterator, extension-methods

As my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56913324/dont-take-last-record-in-linq-c-sharp) question, I came up with this solution:

```
static public IEnumerable<T> SkipLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, int count)
{
  if (data == null || count < 0) yield break;

  Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>(data.Take(count));

  foreach (T item in data.Skip(count))
  {
    queue.Enqueue(item);
    yield return queue.Dequeue();
  }
}
```

It returns all items in the set but the `count` last, but without knowing anything about the size of the data set. I think it's funny and that it's working, but a comment claims that is doesn't. Am I overlooking something?

---

A version with a circular queue could be:

```
static public IEnumerable<T> SkipLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, int count)
{
  if (data == null || count < 0) yield break;
  if (count == 0)
  {
    foreach (T item in data)
      yield return item;
  }
  else
  {
    T[] queue = data.Take(count).ToArray();
    int index = 0;

    foreach (T item in data.Skip(count))
    {
      index %= count;
      yield return queue[index];
      queue[index] = item;
      index++;
    }
  }
}
```

Performance wise they seems to be even.

---

Compared to other solutions like the most obvious:

```
data.Reverse().Skip(count).Reverse()
```

It seems to be at least as fast and for very large set about twice as fast.

Test case:

```
  int count = 20;
  var data = Enumerable.Range(1, count);

  for (int i = 0; i < count + 5; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Skip: {i} => {(string.Join(", ", data.SkipLast1(i)))}");
  }
```

Any comments are useful.

Comment: Ignore my delete answer. I missed one small detail. I like that version with the queue better because it doesn't require this _complex_ index manipulations and has only one loop.

Comment: @t3chb0t: but you have a point in that if `count`is large, the queue gets large, resulting in a large memory consumption an the overhead of copying the data.

Comment: I think it'll rarely get larger than `1` so your caching techinique with the `Queue` is very cool :-) if `count` it would get so large that it would cause memory issues then there is a much bigger issue with the application logic. Or can you think of any example when it would make sense to use `SkipLast(1_000_000)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> if (data == null || count < 0) yield break;
> ```

This behaviour is somewhat consistent with `Take`, but not with `Skip`: `Skip` treats a negative values as a zero. As, indeed, does the [`SkipLast`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skiplast?view=netstandard-2.1) which doesn't appear in .NET Framework.

It should throw on a `null` argument with an `ArgumentNullException`.

---

My only other real issue with the methods is that neither will work with `IEnumerable`s that can't be enumerated multiple times, and will incur overheads in any that can but have to generate the data lazily.

I would go for the slightly more painful:

```cs
if (source == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("Source Enumeration may not be null", nameof(source));

if (count <= 0)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
        yield return item;
}
else
{
    bool yielding = false;
    T[] buffer = new T[count];
    int index = 0;

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        if (index == count)
        {
            index = 0;
            yielding = true;
        }

        if (yielding)
            yield return buffer[index];

        buffer[index] = item;
        index++;
    }
}
```

If I cared about performance, I might consider the following, which reduces the amount of decision making inside the loop (which might make it faster: I'd better benchmark it).

```cs
// just the bit inside the else
T[] buffer = new T[count];

using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
{
    // initial filling of buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!e.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        buffer[i] = e.Current;
    }

    int index = 0;
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return buffer[index];
        buffer[index] = e.Current;
        index = (index + 1) % count;
    }
}
```

---

> Performance wise they seems to be even.

That's encouraging, since `Queue<T>` is also implemented as a circular buffer. You'd hope that the array based version would be a bit lighter, but may consume more memory is `Count > data.Count()`.

Having benchmarked your two proposals, my two proposals, and the .NET Core `SkipLast` (didn't include the `Reverse` based method), it seems the fastest methods are that built into .NET Core (hurray) and my last one, but the difference between test instance (with different data lengths and skip counts) is great. Unfortunately, I messed up and didn't run a third of the .NET Core tests, so the saga of incompetence on my part continues. The code and data can be found in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/VisualMelon/1ab841a5b9204517675236e6645c537d). The only real conclusion I would want to draw from this data (aside from 'use the BCL method if you can') is that your first method is consistently the slowest when the input array isn't empty *in these tests on my machine with it's current workload*. The difference is jolly significant, with your first method requiring twice as much time as others in some cases. *Why* the methods have different performance is less than clear.

Comment: Interesting new optimized versions and tests. I only tested performance on a couple of counts and length and it didn't show much differences. `GetEnumerator()` has often showed to be much faster than a `foreach` loop, which IMO is strange, because the latter calls `GetEnumerator()`.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 cases for which both your and VisualMelon's implementation can be improved:

- If `count` is less than or equal to 0, then you can return `source` directly. This speeds up iteration by removing an unnecessary intermediate step. For this to work, the yielding part of the method has to be moved into another method, but that's easy with local functions.
- If `source is ICollection<T> collection`, then you can return `source.Take(collection.Count - count)`, which is faster and uses less memory because it doesn't need to buffer anything. The higher `count` is, the more of a difference this makes.

The first of these is probably not a very useful edge-case, so it might not be worth the extra code, but I would definitely include the second optimization.

Comment: +1 the BCL implementation does a variation on the former - and the different appears to be measureable - but doesn't for the latter, and there would all benefit from some type specialisation. I suspect I'm going to end up spending a lot of time running benchmarks...

Comment: I have actually made a version after my post that is implemented as your first suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Takning all considerations by VisualMelon and Pieter Witvoet into account a solution could now be:

```
static public IEnumerable<T> SkipLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, int count)
{
  if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
  if (count <= 0) return data;

  if (data is ICollection<T> collection)
    return collection.Take(collection.Count - count);

  IEnumerable<T> Skipper()
  {
    using (var enumer = data.GetEnumerator())
    {
      T[] queue = new T[count];
      int index = 0;

      while (index < count && enumer.MoveNext())
        queue[index++] = enumer.Current;

      index = -1;
      while (enumer.MoveNext())
      {
        index = (index + 1) % count;
        yield return queue[index];
        queue[index] = enumer.Current;
      }
    }
  }

  return Skipper();
}
```

---

**Update**

In order to optimize when the data set is empty, a `MoveNext()` call could be made before the allocation of a potentially large queue array:

```
static public IEnumerable<T> SkipLast2<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, int count)
{
  if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
  if (count <= 0) return data;

  if (data is ICollection<T> collection)
    return collection.Take(collection.Count - count);

  return Skipper();

  IEnumerable<T> Skipper()
  {
    using (var enumer = data.GetEnumerator())
    {
      if (!enumer.MoveNext())
        yield break;

      T[] queue = new T[count];
      queue[0] = enumer.Current;
      int index = 1;

      while (index < count && enumer.MoveNext())
        queue[index++] = enumer.Current;

      index = -1;
      while (enumer.MoveNext())
      {
        index = (index + 1) % count;
        yield return queue[index];
        queue[index] = enumer.Current;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Same benchmark with this (7) and a slight variation (8): [gist](https://gist.github.com/VisualMelon/dfc9b49807ba5e467964fd1dd0af8274). This method consistently out-performs the BCL version, except in the case where the source is empty but the count is high (it uses a `Queue`, so doesn't have to allocate the big array), and performs similarly when the count is otherwise zero with the `Range`. (There is some serious between-test variation, presumably because due to the variable background loading on my machine).

Comment: I'd be cool if `Take` had this behaviour when you specify a negative count.